# Leaflet map showing on only one card when it needs to show on all of them

Tags: javascript, foreach, leaflet

I have 5 card I want that a Leaflet map  will show on each one of them but it only shows on one card,
each map take lat and lot from an array, the index number  for the array is taken by "data-index" attributes on the HTML fill

---

this is the JS fill

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

const mapInfo = [
  { curessTitle: "Big City", mapLat: 51.505, mapLon: 10 },
  { curessTitle: "Food", mapLat: 51.505, mapLon: 0 },
  { curessTitle: "Nature", mapLat: 51.505, mapLon: 0 },
  { curessTitle: "Culture", mapLat: 51.505, mapLon: 0 },
  { curessTitle: "Pepole", mapLat: 51.505, mapLon: 0 },
];

cards.forEach((cards) => {
  let cardDataIndex = cards.dataset.index;
  console.log(cardDataIndex);
  const mymap = L.map("mapid").setView(
[mapInfo[cardDataIndex].mapLat, mapInfo[cardDataIndex].mapLon],
13
  );

  L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
attribution:
  '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  }).addTo(mymap);
});
```

so how can i fixe it? or improve  it ?
any suggestions ?

Comment: How many HTML elements with the id `mapid` do you have in your page?

Comment: @IvanSanchez hi, i have 5 for each div the map should be shown  on

Comment: Each element's `id` must be unique in the document, as explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id and related materials.

Comment: @IvanSanchez ok thanx, so i can’t create it in a loop, just individually ?

Comment: Leaflet map instances can be created inside loops. The matter here is addressing the HTML elements used for the map containers (which is kinda not doable without seeing the structure of your HTML document).

Comment: @IvanSanchez i was  trying  to edit  my  question  and add the HTML fill but i could not  figure it out (I hade an error message ) but I  took  what you said to the hart and change  the id and loop  through the all of the  id, but its still doesn’t  work ,

Answer (score 1):

I adapted one of my [fiddles](https://jsfiddle.net/pkeller3/ac5nem0r/10/) to show you a way to do this.

Here's how I initialized my maps in the fiddle:

```
const myMaps = [];

function initMap() {
  const myArray = ['first', 'second'];
  myArray.forEach((element, index) => {
    // set up the map
    const map = new L.Map('map' + index);

    // create the tile layer with correct attribution
    const osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    const osmAttrib = 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
    const osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
      minZoom: 8,
      maxZoom: 15,
      attribution: osmAttrib
    });

    // start the map 
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(51.503, -0.06), 13);
    map.addLayer(osm);
    myMaps.push(map);
    addMarker(element, map);
    createCircles(map);
  })
}
```

and the html:

```
<div id='map0' class='map'></div>
<div id='map1' class='map'></div>
```

Comment: hi, first thank  you for your time, i tried your  code in vscode(copy and paste ) made the environment preparation, but it didn't work when i opened  it with live server, i liked your idea  and  code do you have suggestions  how can I  make  it  work?

Comment: If you want more help with your particular situation then you'll need to make your own fiddle or plunk showing the exact issue. You can definitely create multiple maps on the same page as shown in the code I posted and the working fiddle I linked to.